# Javascript array with for loop + condition removes unnecessary elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looping through an array and for some reason the loop + condition + splice is removing indexes that shouldn't be removed and keeping others that should be removed, can someone point what's the error with my syntax?

```
arr2 = ['agg', 45, 'ghj', ' ', 9999, 12, 'aa', 'bb'];

function returnAlphanumeric(array){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (typeof array[i] !== "number"){
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log('Your new array is: '+array);
}
returnAlphanumeric(arr2);
```

Comment: You are modifying the array as the loop progresses and that messes up with the indexes. Try as @Ruhul suggested

Comment: @mkaran thanks, but can I have a better and more logical explanation than 'messes up with the indexes' ? :) thx

Comment: When you are at i = 0 for example, that it isn't a number (array[0] is 'agg'), you are going to remove array[i] (array[0), thus, the next iteration when i is going to be equal to 1 array[i] (array[1]) will now be 'ghj'. Take a look at this fiddle on the console :) https://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/4r5mv59z/

Comment: Are string numbers like `'45'` valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use filter method :

```
arr2 = ['agg', 45, 'ghj', ' ', 9999, 12, 'aa', 'bb'];
arr2.filter(a => typeof a === "number"); // 45, 9999, 12
```

Comment: thanks, that's great, but can you explain why my method is working randomly?

Comment: the reason is you are changin the length of the array, which is compared all the time inside for loop continues. splice creates a side effect, which means the length is changing, at some point, you are skipping some elements due to the length and as a result i changes

Comment: thanks, i'll accept your answer (it has a time block of 8 minutes atm)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this, you will have to decrement the counter as splice will make shifts in you array??

```
function returnAlphanumeric(array){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (typeof array[i] !== "number"){
            array.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    console.log('Your new array is: '+array);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the logic of adding the count back, and why my function isn't working?